# How can I run a python model in snowflake?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to run a python worksheet in Snowflake with some external packages. I installed them from the dropdown inside the same python worksheet but when I try to import a certain function, I receive an error message saying this:

```
100357 (P0000): Cannot create a Python function with the specified packages. Please check your packages specification and try again."
Although pandas is inside the list of installed packages
```

I've looked up the versions for the packages to check compatibility and I think the problem does not come from here.
Also, the package or the function I try to import is slashed-underlined, and when I place mi cursor over it it says `couldn't access to <package or function>`.

This is the code I am trying to run:

```py
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col
import pandas

def main(session: snowpark.Session): 
    # Your code goes here, inside the "main" handler.
    tableName = 'information_schema.packages'
    dataframe = session.table(tableName).filter(col("language") == 'python')

    # Print a sample of the dataframe to standard output.
    dataframe.show()

    # Return value will appear in the Results tab.
    return dataframe
```

Comment: I guess that's to run it on the CLI. However, is there a way to build and run on the ui?

Comment: Can you give us more code or details to reproduce?